# MySQL: Dropping a foreign key constraint on an InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, constraints, innodb

I want to remove a foreign key constraint from a table, it is taking a very long time and I wonder what bad things can happen when doing this on a production environment.

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_my_foreign_key;
```

1. Why is it taking that long?
2. Can I speed it up?
3. Is it safe to interrupt the process in the middle?
4. Is there any side effect to running such an operation on a production server?
5. Is there any consistency issue when the alter table fails (lost connection to the server)? What to do in this case when you cannot restart the server with a different configuration (max packet size)?

More information as requested:

- Mysql Server version: 5.5.34
- Foreign key references a column on the same table
- Table has around 80 million of rows
- Key + Constraint on table, ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE works by making a temporary copy of the
>   original table. The alteration is performed on the copy, and then the
>   original table is deleted and the new one is renamed. While ALTER
>   TABLE is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions.
>   Updates and writes to the table are stalled until the new table is
>   ready, and then are automatically redirected to the new table without
>   any failed updates. Thanks.

What about the others cases? Can I prevent such locks?

Comment: You need to add more data about your environment. Server version at first, then what are your tables, how big they are e t.c.

Comment: On update/delete cascade indeed

Comment: If I'm not mistaken MySQL rebuilds all indexes when you run `alter table` - even if the indexes wouldn't be affected by the alter

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: And when the `alter table` fails, is the index left in a consistent state? I've been at it for 2 days and the command never succeeds, it's taking too long, I need to know exactly what's going on and what I can do about it

Comment: Can you confirm the table will not be re-created? Just the index of the table I am altering?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly I must say best practice is always to Test such a change in an offline environment.

Is the table used by replication? if so you would need to remove it first. Also if the table is currently being used it could be locked in a process, check the activity monitor and also look for deadlocks. It would be a good idea to ensure that the key is also not referenced by any index

To safely and correctly remove a foreign key there are many detailed articles that can ben found on Google.